# Replace all Trues in a boolean dataframe with index valule

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

How can I replace all cells in a boolean dataframe (True/False) with the index name of that cell, when "True"? For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [False, True],
        [True, False],

    ],
    index=["abc", "def"],
    columns=list("ab")
)
```

comes out as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [False, abc],
        [def, False],

    ],
    index=["abc", "def"],
    columns=list("ab")
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`df.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

> Replace values where the condition is True.

```
df.mask(df,df.index)
```

---

```
         a      b
abc  False    abc
def    def  False
```