# Replace all Trues in a boolean dataframe with cell position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a boolean dataframe and want to replace the True cells with the position of the cell (as a tuple). Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, False, False],
                  'B': [False, True, True]})
```

[image]

I tried modified versions of `df.mask(df, df.index)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703065/replace-all-trues-in-a-boolean-dataframe-with-index-valule) (e.g., trying `iloc`) but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `stack` to reshape the dataframe as series then use boolean indexing with `loc` to fill the indices obtained using `np.argwhere`, finally use `unstack` to reshape back to dataframe:

```
m = df.stack()
m.loc[m] = pd.Series(map(tuple, np.argwhere(df.to_numpy())), index=m[m].index)
out = m.unstack()
```

Alternatively you can also try `np.argwhere` to get the indices and use indexing with `iat` to set the values in `True` cells with their corresponding indices:

```
out = df.astype(object)
for r, c in np.argwhere(df.to_numpy()):
    out.iat[r, c] = (r, c)
```

Result:

```
print(out)

        A       B
0  (0, 0)   False
1   False  (1, 1)
2   False  (2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {"A": True, "B": False},
    {"A": False, "B": True},
    {"A": False, "B": True},
])

for column in df.columns:
    for index in df.loc[df[column] == True].index:
        df.iloc[index, df.columns.get_loc(column)] = str((index, df.columns.get_loc(column),))
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
        A       B
0  (0, 0)   False
1   False  (1, 1)
2   False  (2, 1)
```

Comment: My bad, fixed the answer

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks. I'm testing it further. How about replacing `["A", "B"]` with   `list(df)` too? To be more generic.

Comment: You could do df.columns (don't do list(DF))